# Forward request to servlet using jquery which in turn forwards to jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I have a js file and based on the below condition I need to display a message or forward the request to servlet which in turn forwards to jsp.

```
var isInIframe = (parent !== window),
    if (isInIframe) {
        //Forward request to servlet
    }else {
        //Display Access denied message
    }
```

I can call a servlet using jquery ajax. But how can I forward request to servlet? once the request is forwarded to servlet then servlet will load some property files and forwards request to some.jsp as below.

```
//Keeps some values using request.setAttribute() then forward the request
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

How can i do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Session` for sending some objects to servlet. Because session remains same for the user throughout the application.

Comment: Is it possible to forward the request from jquery to servlet?

Comment: @user755806 As per my experience, I cant find a way to do this. For one of my project I wanted to do the same and I search for it. But can't find the solution and pass the object in Session. :(

Answer (score 0):

JQuery/Javascript does not "forward" requests to web applications. It makes new requests via AJAX or redirects. JQuery itself does not handle HTTP requests.

You need to make an AJAX request for this. I assume that JSP is the presentation layer of your web application. So just make an ajax request to your web app using the JQuery $.ajax() method..

You can handle the response using the AJAX callback function

Comment: @ cowls thanks for ur reply.i dont want to handle the response which i get back. anyway my servlet has to redirect to different jsp. can i achieve this?

Comment: My goal is, call the servlet, servlet will load some property files then forwards request to jsp which will actually displays a page..

Comment: It sounds like a standard http request to a web application? Servlet handles the request, reads the properties file and then loads the JSP. How is your java web app configured? Are you using a framework?

Comment: Nope..u understood my problem....i am using plain jquery ajax, jsp and servlets. Does my approach really work?

Comment: it sounds like you dont fully understand how each of the components you mention fit together. You can set up your web application to receive a request, load some data and present it with a JSP file. You can then call that application via javascript either with an AJAX request or a redirect

Answer (score 0):

`Servlet` and `jsp` are server-side components. The Server receives [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) requests and dispatches a `Servlet` to handle them by producing a corresponding HTTP response for each of them, some times with the help of a `jsp`.

`Javascript` is a client-side component. It runs in the browser. When the `javascript` runs, the HTTP response containing the HTML you see in the browser has already been sent, so the `Servlet` is completely out of the picture. You cannot `forward` to it like you are imagining with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

What you can do is use `ajax` to construct and send a new HTTP request that will be handled by a `Servlet`.